# symfony2 app_dev.php route get 404 but works with app.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

i have an issue with my apache configuration and my several symfony projects.

Debian version : 7.8
apache version : 2.2.22 with mpm_prefork

My vhost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/web
    ServerName test.xxx.com
    <Directory /var/www/test/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my test project, .htaccess look like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The rewrite module is activated (i have tested id by comment rewrite directives in .htaccess and call my url).

When i call the prod url like test.xxx.com and test.xxx.com/something, it works.
But when i call app_dev.php url, the front controller is never executed.
Example:
I call test.xxx.com/something, apache errors logs says "File does not exist" and i don't have any logs in dev.log in my symfony project.

I don't understand why the frontcontroller is not executed on my dev environment.

My app_dev.php file :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Why did you edited the  .htaccess in first place? Didn't the default one work? https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess

Comment: I have tried with this .htaccess and i have the same issue. This issue occurs for every symfony project on my server. I have the same project on other server and this issue doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please check symfony 2.8 app_dev.php file :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.8.6/web/app_dev.php

`$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';` becomes `$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';`

and `require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';` disappears

Also, change the RewriteRule in your htaccess to redirect to app_dev.php instead of app.php

Comment: My symfony version is 2.3 currently. I know thath i must upgrade it but my project is installed on several servers and i don't have the time to upgrade it  this month. As i said in a comment, this issue occurs on every symfony project on my server but not occurs on the other server that i have for the same project.

Comment: have you tried to use the default app_dev.php from 2.3 ?
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/web/app_dev.php

Comment: yes, i have the same issue. I think there is a problem in my apache configuration because i have made a comparison between apache configuration files on my differents servers and there are the same. I think, i will reinstall apache and php (and delete /etc/apache/ and /etc/php5 files before) to check if the problem still occurs.